# Email when specific ranges are labeled

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Need a little help, the code is not sending the email when the column is being edited.
What I am trying to accomplish, first, is that when column F is marked with an "x" it will send an email to notify Boss#2 that this report is ready for them to review.
In the next code I wrote, I would like for when the columns L, O, R, U, and X are labeled with an "X" it will send an email to two users.

Here is the sample of the sheet I am working with:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rzcppf213f1EZMybw9zeD51FVfhRLGvNKHBn00Fi6wk/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the code I modified. I just started with the first part and I am assuming I have to do it like so for each column I want to be notified if edited.

```
//First function to send emails to Boss#2 after Boss#1 completes a column in range F
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Property Checklist")
  var budgetRange = ss.getRange("F6"); 
  var propertyRange = budgetRange.getValue();
  if (propertyRange == 'X'){
  
  var message = 'Hi Boss#2! \n \nA budget is ready for your review!\n \nVisit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes';
  var subject = 'Budget Timeline: Ready for Review';
  MailApp.sendEmail('xxx@gmail.com', subject, message);
    }
}

//Second function to send emails to Boss#1 & #2 for edits on column L
function sendNotification2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Property Checklist")
  var budgetRange = ss.getRange("L6:L"); 
  var propertyRange = budgetRange.getValue();
  if (propertyRange == 'X'){
  
  var message = 'Attention! \n \nA budget has been sent to the client!\n \nVisit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes';
  var subject = 'Budget Timeline: Sent to Client';
  MailApp.sendEmail('xxx@gmail.com, xxx2@outlook.com', subject, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: By **to two users when it's labeled with an "X"** what you actually mean? When F is marked the code should send an email to the emailAddress in the **Emails** Sheet. Anyway, when L, O, R, U and X are marked the second email is specified in the **Emails** Sheet?. You probably want to take a look into the [Google Apps Script > Gmail Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body).

Comment: When a section is completed columns F, L, O, R, U and X will be labeled with an "X". Only for column F, the email needs to go to one person, but for the other columns, it will need to go to two users.
I might just need to rewrite the notification to specify those columns.
Also, for doing that, how do you recommend I modify the range code?

Comment: In order to better understand your question: Do you want to check the "X" when the Spreadsheet has been modified by someone and then run the function or do you want to manually run the **sendNotification** function and check the "X" at the same time?

Comment: I want it to send automatically when the X has been entered.
I did add a trigger, but whether it's removing it or adding it, it just sends emails like crazy.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

You can handle it by adding the `onEdit` trigger.

```
function sendNotification() {
  var message = 'Hi Boss#2! \n \nA budget is ready for your review!\n \nVisit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes';
  var subject = 'Budget Timeline: Ready for Review';
  MailApp.sendEmail('xxx@gmail.com', subject, message);
}

function sendNotification2() {
  var message = 'Attention! \n \nA budget has been sent to the client!\n \nVisit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes';
  var subject = 'Budget Timeline: Sent to Client';
  MailApp.sendEmail('xxx@gmail.com, xxx2@outlook.com', subject, message);
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var NOTIFIED = "Notified"
  var cellValue = e.range.getValue();
  var cellNotation = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var cellLetter = cellNotation[0];
  var cellNumber = cellNotation.slice(1);
  var cellArray = ['F', 'L', 'O', 'R', 'U', 'X'];

  // First of all check the column letter
  if (cellArray.includes(cellLetter) && cellValue.toUpperCase() === 'X') {
    if (cellLetter === 'F') {

      if (e.range.getNote() !== NOTIFIED) {
        sendNotification();
        e.range.setNote(NOTIFIED); // Mark as already sent
      }

    } else {
      // Check all the columns needed in the row
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Property Checklist");
      var valueL = sheet.getRange("L" + cellNumber).getValue();
      var valueO = sheet.getRange("O" + cellNumber).getValue();
      var valueR = sheet.getRange("R" + cellNumber).getValue();
      var valueU = sheet.getRange("U" + cellNumber).getValue();
      var valueX = sheet.getRange("X" + cellNumber).getValue();

      if (valueL.toUpperCase() === 'X' &&
          valueO.toUpperCase() === 'X' &&
          valueR.toUpperCase() === 'X' &&
          valueU.toUpperCase() === 'X' &&
          valueX.toUpperCase() === 'X') {

            if (sheet.getRange("X" + cellNumber).getNote() !== NOTIFIED) {
              sendNotification2();
              sheet.getRange("X" + cellNumber).setNote(NOTIFIED); // Mark as already sent
            }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

By separating the 2 functions and evaluating the column F or columns L, O, R, U, X. This workaround get the value in the current cell edited and looks for the missing **X** in the same row, when it comes to F, just FNumber (where **Number** is the number of the row) is treated. Otherwise if the value edited is within the columns L, O, R, U  or X, we check if there are not any **X** values remaining.

Last but not least, when a "boss" has been notified by using one of the functions above (sendNotification or sendNotification2), this script will write a note in the last cell in order to avoid sending duplicate email notifications, in other words `sendNotification` is called if there's not a note in the FNumber cell saying "Notified" as well as `sendNotification2` is called when there's not a note in the XNumber (also saying "Notified).

### Option 2

This is a workaround that affects the UI workspace in your Spreadsheet and the purpose is to save some steps **but it doesn't automate your notifications** because it just adds a menu button in the top of your current menu and adds 2 more buttons in it where you can call your functions manually.

```
function sendNotification() {
  var message = 'Hi Boss#2! \n \nA budget is ready for your review!\n \nVisit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes';
  var subject = 'Budget Timeline: Ready for Review';
  MailApp.sendEmail('xxx@gmail.com', subject, message);
}

function sendNotification2() {
  var message = 'Attention! \n \nA budget has been sent to the client!\n \nVisit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes';
  var subject = 'Budget Timeline: Sent to Client';
  MailApp.sendEmail('xxx@gmail.com, xxx2@outlook.com', subject, message);
}

function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Custom Menu - Notifications')
      .addItem('Send Notification Function', 'sendNotification')
      .addItem('Send Notification 2 Function', 'sendNotification2')
      .addToUi();
}
```

### Reference

[Ui > createMenu function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#createmenucaption)

[Spreadsheet > Range > setNote function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotenote)

Comment: Hey Jose, thanks for your help. I am trying to do Option 1 since it's automated. I am getting an error on line 15. If you can assist me with that, I would appreciate it.

Comment: The `onEdit` function won't work if you run it manually. In fact, the `onEdit` purpose is to handle changes on your Sheet. For example if you fill the cell F6 with an **X** after that you will see a note in it which says **Notified** which is a note that avoids duplicate notifications so if you re-edit that same cell you will notice that nothing happens because of that note. let me know if that works for you.